# Excel Date Range

Tags: excel

These are emails sent my a specific salesperson:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how often on average does she send emails. The hourly basis or daily to make it easy. I've tried both a CountIF function and a vlookpup but both didn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you can't see the data the emails come in as **`"Wed, 18 May 2016 13:09:18"`**

Comment: How many datas do you have?

Comment: How about a pivot-table summary?

Comment: I'm trying to change the data to day/month/year; i don't need time. When I use format cells I get nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would change the formatting of column B to something like DD MMM then do a CountIf to total how many emails each day. (Or DD MMM HH then CountIf to see how many in that hour). You can do this by formatting the cell then inputting those date codes in custom format (YY or YYYY to include year, play around with them to get what you want).

If Excel isn't reading these values as dates then try something like this: =MID(B1,5,12) in column C next to them, that will grab just the date (e.g. 25 May 2016) then you can countif that column... Use =MID(B1,5,15) to get the first 2 digits of the time for an hourly breakdown. Please note that this will only work for May.

For other months you can change the number of characters (the last section of formula) to fit it in.

Comment: How do you go about changing it? I think I just want to switch it to, i.e. 3/14/15; to calculate it daily. I click the specific type but it still doesn't change.

Comment: If Excel isn't reading these values as dates then try something like this: